# What does being Abelian have to do at all with the proof?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I don't understand why the proof needs to consider cases that $G$ is Abelian and non-Abelian.

> If $|G|=p^n$ where $n>1$ then show that $G$ cannot be simple.

It uses the theorem

> If $G$ is a finite p-group and non trivial then the centre is non trivial i.e. $Z(G) \neq \{e\}$

Well, here's how it starts with the proof

> The theorem tells us that $Z(G)$ is non trivial. If $G$ is not Abelian then $Z(G)$ is a non trivial normal subgroup so $G$ is not simple.
>
> Consider $G$ when $G$ is Abelian...

Wait, Doesn't $Z(G)$ work as a normal subgroup regardless of Abelian-nes of $G$? $G$ is a finite p-group so $Z(G)$ is non trivial anyway, and isn't it normal anyway too?

$Z(G)$ is essentially the elements $a \in G$ that for *ANY* $g \in G$, $ga=ag$ so that conjugate stays still, fixed. so $gZ(G)=Z(G)g$ since $ga=ag, \forall a \in Z(G)$ no? Why does $Z(G)$ not be normal if $G$ is Abelian? I don't get it.

Comment: A priori $Z(G)$ could be all of $G$.  They are just pointing out that in that case the group is abelian, hence easy to analyze.

Comment: To be clear:  there are abelian simple groups, of course.  Namely the cyclic groups of prime order.  In those cases we do indeed have $Z(G)=G$.

Comment: But, then, if we're concerned about $Z(G)=G$ happening, shouldn't that apply to the case of non Abelian too? It seems to assert that $Z(G) \neq G$ in the case it is non Abelian. Why can we assert so?

Comment: If $Z(G)=G$ then $G$ is abelian.  The center is defined to be those elements which commute with every element in $G$ and if every element of $G$ commutes with every element of $G$ then $G$ is abelian, by definition.

Comment: Addressing the question in the final paragraph: $Z(G)$ **is** normal if $G$ is abelian, but it is not a proper subgroup (it is all of $G$), so we need to find some other normal subgroup to show that $G$ is not simple.

Answer (score 3):

A group $G$ is simple if and only if its only normal subgroups are $\{e\}$ and $G$.

If $G$ is a $p$-group, then $Z(G)\ne\{e\}$. If $Z(G)\ne G$, the group is not simple because we have found a normal subgroup different from $\{e\}$ and $G$.

Note that the hypothesis that $n>1$ has not been used for this case.

*If $Z(G)=G$ (that is, $G$ is abelian), we have not yet found a (normal) subgroup different from $\{e\}$ and $G$ and we must exploit $n>1$.*

If there exists $g\in G$ with $g^p\ne e$, then $H=\{x\in G:x^p=e\}$ is a subgroup with $\{e\}\ne H\ne G$. Otherwise, $x^p=e$ for all $x\in G$ and we can take $g\in G$ with order $p$; then $\{e\}\ne\langle g\rangle\ne G$, so $G$ is not simple.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler (no pun intended) argument for the case $Z(G) = G$ and $n > 1$ would be to use Cauchy's theorem to find an element in $Z(G)$ with order $p$. The subgroup generated by this element is normal (as is any subgroup of $Z(G)$), hence $G$ is not simple. (In fact, this argument also works if $Z(G) < G$.)

Comment: @Bungo Yes, it's simpler. On the other hand, Cauchy's theorem is not really needed.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I just didn't know about this $Z(G)=G$ iff $G$ is Abelian...is that a theorem somewhere? I might want to look it up

Comment: @Kydo If $G$ is abelian, then every element commutes with any other element, so $Z(G)=G$; conversely, $Z(G)$ is abelian.